# How to delete files from the "Masters" folders of "Photos" library

Tags: photos, spotlight

I am using osX Sierra 10.12.6, and about a year ago, scanned some slides for a friend and for convenience and some quick editing put them  temporarily in the "Photos" application, then deleted them.

However today a search with Spotlight reveals that they are still stored (or appear to be) multiple times, typically 5 times such as "picture1.jpg" located in the following paths:

"Masters:2018:02:17:20180217-091606:picture1.jpg" 
or : 
"Masters:2018:02:17:20180217-092544:picture1.jpg", etc...

The pictures are not visible in the "Photos" interface, and a search in the "Photos" search engine on file names returns nothing. But the pictures can be opened normally from the Finder where they appear to have all normal attributes.

I have tried to rebuild the "Photos" Library, but this did not change the situation. How to get these files erased forever in a clean way ?

Comment: Of course they are not in the recently deleted folder, that is currently empty. I could of course delete them directly in the "Masters" folder, but I am worried about this affecting the database integrity. I am also wondering how the situation originated, and as well if they are not many other cases that are likely to waste storage space.

Comment: Don't even consider deleting them directly from the Masters or Resources folders. See if opening Photos while keeping Cmd-Opt pressed and then "Repair library" gets rid of them.